# I noticed a .myPassword file in my home folder root. Is this supposed to be there?

Tags: terminal, password, user-account

I ran "$ ls -a" in Terminal from my home directory and it listed a .myPassword file which contained my user account password. Is this file where the password is stored? It seems like it should not be that accessible.

Comment: Definitely shouldn't be there. did a quick Google search, couldn't find anything about this file. I'd be interested to know what app puts it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not where your password is stored.  At least by the system, no way.  I don't have one there, which tells me you have a 3rd-party app that's doing this.  Take a close look.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I removed the file. Right after doings so, I remembered that I could have looked at the file ownership/permissions. Perhaps it would have given a clue as to its origin. Oh well. I can check later to see if it reappears.